# tsoutliers dependency issue: dependency KFKSDS has non-zero exit status?

Tags: r, ubuntu, time-series, outliers

While working on outlier detection on a time series data. I came across `[tsoutliers][1]` packages that does implement [Chen and Liu's time series](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1993.10594321#.U6w4BXLkv2c) outlier detection. But I am unable to install tsoutliers in R

> install.packages("tsoutliers")

I am getting the following dependency errors

> In file included from KF-deriv.cpp:1:0: KFKSDS.h:14:28: fatal error:
>   gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
>   /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:143: recipe for target 'KF-deriv.o' failed
>   make: *** [KF-deriv.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package
>   ‘KFKSDS’
>   * removing ‘/home/atoffy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/KFKSDS’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘KFKSDS’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘KFKSDS’ is not available for
>   package ‘stsm’
>   * removing ‘/home/atoffy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/stsm’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘stsm’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘stsm’, ‘KFKSDS’ are not
>   available for package ‘tsoutliers’
>   * removing ‘/home/atoffy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/tsoutliers’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tsoutliers’
>   had non-zero exit status

More specifically

> recipe for target 'KF-deriv.o' failed

Can anyone help me to install the same?

Comment: > version                                    
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.3                         
year           2015                        
month          12                          
day            10                          
svn rev        69752                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the same by installing

> [libgsl0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623339/altough-i-installed-gsl-library-g-cannot-compile-my-code)

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

Comment: On Ubuntu I had to use this instead: `sudo apt install libgs-dev`.
I followed this example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/121810/what-does-libgs10-dev-relate-to

Comment: Actually, I realized I was typing `libgs10-dev` with the number `1` instead of `libgsl0-dev` with the letter `l`... I hope someone else can learn from my mistakes, `sudo apt install libgsl0-dev` should do the trick!